# Casting an object's class

Tags: java

My previous OOP experience has been with Objective-C (which is dynamically typed), however, I am now learning Java. I want to iterate over an ArrayList of objects and perform a certain method on them. Every object in the ArrayList is of the same class. In Objective-C, I would just check in each iteration that the object was the correct class, and then run the method, but that technique is not possible in Java:

```
for (Object apple : apples) {
        if (apple.getClass() == Apple.class) {
            apple.doSomething(); //Generates error: cannot find symbol
        }
    }
```

How do I 'tell' the compiler which class the objects in the ArrayList belong to?

Comment: Is this an list of only apples (as the name "apples" suggests) or is it a heterogenous list that contains apples and some other stuff? danben's suggestion is the right way to go for the former. akf's answer is a more literal translation of what you posted, but really only makes sense for a heterogenous list (ie: where you expected non-apples to be in the list).

Comment: I'll edit to make it more clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Java 5 and later, collecton types are generified.  So you would have this:

```
ArrayList<Apple> a = getAppleList(); // list initializer

for (Apple apple : a) {
    apple.doSomething();
}
```

It is not generally good practice to have `ArrayList`s of `Object` unless you specifically need your `ArrayList` to be able to hold different types of `Objects`.  Usually that is not the case, and you can use heterogenous collections for increased type-safety.

Comment: Might be a bit clearer if you just said "Apple"/"apple" instead of "MyClass"/"myclass".

Comment: I changed that quite a while ago; maybe you hadn't refreshed the page?

Answer (score 5):

for traditional casting, consider this:

```
for (Object apple : apples) {
    if (apple instanceof Apple) { //performs the test you are approximating
        ((Apple)apple).doSomething(); //does the cast
    }
}
```

in later versions of Java, [Generics](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf) were introduced that obviate the need for these sorts of tests.

Comment: That's a new-style for loop, so I'm pretty sure he's got generics. Also, even pre-generics you'd generally forgo the instanceof check unless you were actually expecting to skip over non-Apples (and if the latter is true, generics don't help you anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [section on casting from the Java Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) should answer that question.

(Or, if you declare the ArrayList yourself, use an approapriate type parameter as danben suggests=

Comment: It didn't, and anyway, you're not meant to tell people to RTFM on SO.

Comment: You asked: "How do I tell the compiler which class the objects belong to". The tutorial writes: "However, we can tell the compiler that we promise to assign a MountainBike to obj by explicit casting: MountainBike myBike = (MountainBike)obj;"

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast `Object` apple to `Apple`.

```
((Apple)apple).doSomething();
```

But in this specific case, it's better to use;

```
for(Apple apple : apples){
    apple.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Actually if his collection is not properly typed (with generics), this won't work.  Which SUCKS by the way.

Comment: I just trusted his asumptation, *"Every object in the ArrayList is of the same class."*